# Menu mnemonic doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, menu, mnemonics

```
optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
optionsMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
optionsMenu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Options Menu");
menuBar.add(optionsMenu);
```

However, when I actually hit O in runtime, the menu doesn't open. What gives?

Comment: It should respond to alt-o, not just o.

Comment: How do I make it respond to O?

Comment: To respond to just O use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) not mnemonics.